# Window Function Tie breaker on other field to get the Latest Record

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following data, where the data is partitioned by the stores  and month id and ordered by amount in order to get the primary vendor for the store.

I need a tie breaker if the amount is equal between two vendors, 
then if one of the tied vendor was the previous months most sales vendor, make that vendor as  the most sales vendor  for the month.

The look back will increase if there is a tie again. Lag of 1 month will not work if there is tie again. Worst case scenario we will have more duplicates in previous month also.

sample data

```scala
val data = Seq((201801,      10941,            115,  80890.44900, 135799.66400),
               (201801,      10941,            3,  80890.44900, 135799.66400) ,
               (201712,      10941,            3, 517440.74500, 975893.79000),
               (201712,      10941,            115, 517440.74500, 975893.79000),
               (201711,      10941,            3 , 371501.92100, 574223.52300),
               (201710,      10941,            115, 552435.57800, 746912.06700),
               (201709,      10941,            115,1523492.60700,1871480.06800),
               (201708,      10941,            115,1027698.93600,1236544.50900),
               (201707,      10941,            33 ,1469219.86900,1622949.53000)
               ).toDF("MTH_ID", "store_id" ,"brand" ,"brndSales","TotalSales")
```

Code:

```scala
val window = Window.partitionBy("store_id","MTH_ID").orderBy("brndSales")
val res = data.withColumn("rank",rank over window)
```

Output:

```
    +------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----+
 |MTH_ID|store_id|brand|  brndSales| TotalSales|rank|
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----+
|201801|   10941|  115|  80890.449| 135799.664|   1|
|201801|   10941|    3|  80890.449| 135799.664|   1|
|201712|   10941|    3| 517440.745|  975893.79|   1|
|201712|   10941|  115| 517440.745|  975893.79|   1|
|201711|   10941|  115| 371501.921| 574223.523|   1|
|201710|   10941|  115| 552435.578| 746912.067|   1|
|201709|   10941|  115|1523492.607|1871480.068|   1|
|201708|   10941|  115|1027698.936|1236544.509|   1|
|201707|   10941|   33|1469219.869| 1622949.53|   1|
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----+
```

My rank is 1 for both  1 and 2 records, but my rank should be 1 for second record based on previous month max dollars

I am expecting the following output.

```
    +------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----+
    |MTH_ID|store_id|brand|  brndSales| TotalSales|rank|
    +------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----+
    |201801|   10941|  115|  80890.449| 135799.664|   2|
    |201801|   10941|    3|  80890.449| 135799.664|   1|
    |201712|   10941|    3| 517440.745|  975893.79|   1|
    |201712|   10941|  115| 517440.745|  975893.79|   1|
    |201711|   10941|    3| 371501.921| 574223.523|   1|
    |201710|   10941|  115| 552435.578| 746912.067|   1|
    |201709|   10941|  115|1523492.607|1871480.068|   1|
    |201708|   10941|  115|1027698.936|1236544.509|   1|
    |201707|   10941|   33|1469219.869| 1622949.53|   1|
    +------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----+
```

Should I write a UDAF? Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Can you provide your sample data as SQL `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, not whatever that is?

Comment: This is data-frame spark approach

Comment: Do you mind if both entries (in your example) will be set with rank=2?

Comment: In standard SQL I'd try to use recursive CTE to walk through the months carrying over the best vendor from the previous month for comparisons.

Comment: What should happen if you cannot not break the tie even when looking back in months?

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally Then i can order by brand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with 2 windows. First, you will need to use the lag() function to carry over the previous month's sales values so that you can use that in your rank window. here's that part in pyspark:

```
lag_window = Window.partitionBy("store_id", "brand").orderBy("MTH_ID")
lag_df = data.withColumn("last_month_sales", lag("brndSales").over(lag_window))
```

Then edit your window to include that new column:

```
window = Window.partitionBy("store_id","MTH_ID").orderBy("brndSales", "last_month_sales")
lag_df.withColumn("rank",rank().over(window)).show()
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+----+
|MTH_ID|store_id|brand|  brndSales| TotalSales|last_month_sales|rank|
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+----+
|201711|   10941|   99| 371501.921| 574223.523|            null|   1|
|201709|   10941|  115|1523492.607|1871480.068|     1027698.936|   1|
|201707|   10941|   33|1469219.869| 1622949.53|            null|   1|
|201708|   10941|  115|1027698.936|1236544.509|            null|   1|
|201710|   10941|  115| 552435.578| 746912.067|     1523492.607|   1|
|201712|   10941|    3| 517440.745|  975893.79|            null|   1|
|201801|   10941|    3|  80890.449| 135799.664|      517440.745|   1|
|201801|   10941|  115|  80890.449| 135799.664|      552435.578|   2|
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+----------------+----+
```

Comment: As i added in the question, there can be duplicate records in previous month also, then we cannot use the lag of one month. Look back is not fixed to one month.

Comment: I want to write UDAF, but my window is not limited to  one

Answer (score 0):

For each row, collect an array of that brands previous sales, in a (Month, Sales) struct.

```
val storeAndBrandWindow = Window.partitionBy("store_id", "brand").orderBy($"MTH_ID")
val df1 = data.withColumn("brndSales_list", collect_list(struct($"MTH_ID", $"brndSales")).over(storeAndBrandWindow))
```

Reverse that array with a UDF.

```
val returnType = ArrayType(StructType(Array(StructField("month", IntegerType), StructField("sales", DoubleType))))
val reverseUdf = udf((list: Seq[Row]) => list.reverse, returnType)
val df2 = df1.withColumn("brndSales_list", reverseUdf($"brndSales_list"))
```

And then sort by the array.

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("store_id", "MTH_ID").orderBy($"brndSales_list".desc)
val df3 = df2.withColumn("rank", rank over window).orderBy("MTH_ID", "brand")
df3.show(false)
```

Result

```
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|MTH_ID|store_id|brand|brndSales  |TotalSales |brndSales_list                                                                           |rank|
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|201707|10941   |33   |1469219.869|1622949.53 |[[201707, 1469219.869]]                                                                  |1   |
|201708|10941   |115  |1027698.936|1236544.509|[[201708, 1027698.936]]                                                                  |1   |
|201709|10941   |115  |1523492.607|1871480.068|[[201709, 1523492.607], [201708, 1027698.936]]                                           |1   |
|201710|10941   |115  |552435.578 |746912.067 |[[201710, 552435.578], [201709, 1523492.607], [201708, 1027698.936]]                     |1   |
|201711|10941   |99   |371501.921 |574223.523 |[[201711, 371501.921]]                                                                   |1   |
|201712|10941   |3    |517440.745 |975893.79  |[[201712, 517440.745]]                                                                   |1   |
|201801|10941   |3    |80890.449  |135799.664 |[[201801, 80890.449], [201712, 517440.745]]                                              |1   |
|201801|10941   |115  |80890.449  |135799.664 |[[201801, 80890.449], [201710, 552435.578], [201709, 1523492.607], [201708, 1027698.936]]|2   |
+------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
```