# Pyspark: orderby top 10 count descending breaking ties?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe where I am grouping by id1 and id2, then ordering by count in descending order.  I want to break tie breakers by whichever has the higher rate value.  Here is what I have for my code currently:

```
df.groupBy('ID1', 'ID2').agg((avg("amount")/avg("distance")).alias("rate"), count("*").alias("count")).orderBy(desc('count'), desc('rate')).limit(10).show()
```

and my output is:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534663/window-function-tie-breaker-on-other-field-to-get-the-latest-record

Comment: My apologies, but I am not seeing the connection here since the link you have above is referring to partitioning and rank as opposed to just orderBy count and dealing with a tie breaker.  Any further insight would be fantastic! (Sorry new to pyspark)

Comment: Looks like you already achieved your request? The `34`s are already ordered by `rate`, same as `23`s?

Comment: There should only be 1 instance of 34 and 23, so in other words, the top 10 unique count values where the tie breaker is whichever has the larger rate.  So For the 34's it would only keep the (ID1, ID2) pair corresponding to (239, 238).